# Selectively enable Action Bar on some versions of Android

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I have an application that I'm currently porting to tablets.  During this transitional period I would like to have the app look very honeycomb-like when installed on tablets.  In particular, I would like the the app to have an Action bar when installed on tablets.  However, I do NOT want an action bar when the app is installed on phones, since I do not want to redesign the phone experience to accommodate an action bar at this time.

What is the best way to have my app look the same as it currently does when installed on phones, but add an action bar when it's installed on tablets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to accomplish what I wanted by using a different style for phones and for tablets.

In res/values/styles.xml I have my default (phone) style configured to inherit from Theme.Light

```
<style name="my_theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    ...
</style>
```

In res/values-xlarge-mdpi/styles.xml I use Theme.Holo, because the [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) docs specify that all Theme.Holo activities have the action bar.

```
<style name="my_theme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    ...
</style>
```

And of course I have my AndroidManifest specifies the theme to use:

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/my_theme"
    ...
/>
```

This seems to give me an action bar on tablet devices but no action bar on phone devices.

Comment: but why you want to avoid actionbar on ICS phones? look at gmail ICS app, it has it.

Comment: The question explains "... since I do not want to redesign the phone experience to accommodate an action bar at this time."  You may not agree with my desire, but it is explained right in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separate layout file for your tablet devices. Append large or xlarge to the end of the directory will allow only those devices access to it.

For example:

```
layout-large
drawable-xlarge
values-large
```

Comment: In particular, you will need to do this because you cannot really use the OS's own action bar and will need to fake one yourself. Ice Cream Sandwich supports action bars on phones -- I am not aware of a way to tell Android to not use an action bar on ICS phones but to use it on other ICS devices.